# Can I put "if" or "once" after "that"?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, word-order

For example, is the following sentence correct?
"Be aware that if/once you cheat, I'll cut your exam paper, and your mark will be zero."
Or, should I say, "If/Once you cheat, be aware that I'll cut your exam paper, and your mark will be zero."?

Comment: The  only real issue is with cut an exam paper. Do you use scissors for that?

Comment: Using ***once*** rather than ***if*** strongly implies (1) that the postulated future event/situation *will in fact come to pass*. It also strongly implies (2) that *there will be no turning back or otherwise attempting to avoid any specified consequences*. So one might argue on the basis of (1) that the teacher *shouldn't* use it (because it's improper of him to assume his students will cheat). But he might do so on the basis of (2), because he wants to impress upon his students that they will *definitely* get 0 marks if they cheat (but it's unspecified how the teacher will know this).

Comment: Note the difference between ***If** he marries me I will be faithful* and ***Once** he marries me I will be faithful*. The former strongly implies the speaker thinks it's at least *possible* he might not marry her. The latter strongly implies she thinks the marriage is bound to take place.

Comment: @Lambie: It's ***cut*** as in ***remove*** (from the set of papers which will be graded, so they won't get any marks).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not usual phrasing, You mean: remove the exam from the stack of papers to be graded. In any case, cut is not great here. invalidate is better. (Please note: I find these long-winded explanations all squished up into a comment difficult to follow. )

Comment: @Lambie: Sure, it's not the *usual* (= *most common*) verb for the context. But that doesn't imply there's anything wrong with it. Any pupils who weren't already familiar with the usage will get a pretty clear idea of the meaning from context (and what they already know about *cutting classes* or being *cut from the football team*), so arguably the teacher could be using his warning as a vehicle to improve their linguistic agility.

Comment: @FumbleFingers cut from the football team and cut classes are very different, come on. Cut your exam paper is simply not idiomatic. Why are you saying it is??

Comment: @Lambie: Forget about "idiomatic", since it's unclear whether "non-idiomatic" equates to (1) "unacceptable", or simply (2) "not particularly common". The bottom line is you think (1) applies to OP's cited usage here, but I lean towards (2). It's much the same as this example from [How to write a great awards entry:](https://www.b2bmarketing.net/en-gb/resources/features/how-write-great-awards-entry) *Don't give the judges any reason **to cut your submission***, which is fine by me. It's certainly not worth getting exercised about as an "incorrect" usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would use  these two words: when and if

Comment: @Lambie You talked a lot about the word "cut" in my sentence. Well, I'm sorry for using a wrong word. Last night, at the time of asking this question, I thought that two of the meanings of the word "cut" are these: (1) to divide something like paper into two parts using scissors, knife, etc. (2) to devide something like paper or cardboard into a lot of peices using hands, usually in order to destroy it. But today, when I went to school and talked about the word "cut" with my friend, he told me that the second meaning doesn't belong to the word "cut". So could you suggest a proper word to me?

Comment: I mean, I'm trying to say that if you cheat, I devide your exam paper to a lot of small pieces and put them in the trash, and your mark will be zero. Actually I'm not really a teacher, but I'd like to know how to correct my sentence.

Comment: @Javad Bayat I will cut up [that means with scissors] your exam paper. Cut up. Cut something up into pieces. It has to be that phrasal verb based on your clarification.

Comment: I mean, with hands, not with scissors.

Comment: @JavadBayat Ok, then, tear up (tear, tore, torn). Tear up your exam paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Be aware that **if and when** you cheat, I'll **cut up** your exam paper and your mark will be zero."

However, I suggest changing cut your exam paper to invalidating your exam paper.

In English, warnings are often delivered by using if and when x, then y.

That said, you could also use: if and once.

My answer is edited to reflect the info in the OP's comment to me.

To get the idea of pieces in English, we say: to cut up

To cut up the vegetables for dinner. And not: to cut the vegetables.

I cut my finger with the knife.

Cut and cut up are different.

Also, to tear up an exam paper.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, either is OK.  However, that is not something a professor would say ... at least I don't think anyone would say that.In this context it would appropriate to use "if" and rewrite simply as, "Be aware that if you are caught cheating, your mark will be zero."

If this were to happen in real life, I would think that most institutions would also expel the student.  In this case one would say, "Be aware that if you are caught cheating, not only will your mark will be zero, you will face expulsion from this institution."

Comment: There's an argument for saying that the cited teacher was very specifically trying to *avoid* explicitly making the point given in your rephrasing. By changing to ***IF** [you are caught cheating]*, you're implicitly allowing for the possibility that they might cheat without being caught. He has carefully avoided doing this, as a rhetorical device intended to discourage the students from thinking along those lines. He wants them to be thinking ***cheating** = bad outcome*, not ***being caught** = bad outcome*.

Comment: The teacher could use both: if or once etc.

Comment: Your answers are perfect. However I didn't want to pretend I'm a teacher. I'm just a student. I just wanted to know if it's grammatical to use "if" or "once" after "that". By your answers, I also understood that using "Once" instead of "if" can make the students nervous because they think they will really get zero and lose their exam paper as soon as they cheat. By saying "if you are caught cheating", I soften my sentence because I pretend that the students "may" cheat.